Animating sections on scroll with Framer Motion
I would like to know how to achieve this effect on scroll - https://www.loom.com/share/aea16788e5c54bff82f43ff22562db7e?sid=bf339a76-b9d6-4bcc-a16c-e623ad655323
I am using Framer motion in Next.js and I am not sure how to approach this. Could you guys please point me in a direction in which this can be solved?
I've tried by myself, but did not go very far, here is the code:

import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { motion, useScroll, useTransform } from "framer-motion";

interface Props {
  activityName: string;
  title: string;
  text: string;
  linkText?: string | undefined;
  linkUrl?: string | undefined;
  imageUrl: string;
  className?: string;
}

const ActivityFieldsSection = ({
  activityName,
  title,
  text,
  linkText,
  linkUrl = "",
  imageUrl,
  className,
}: Props) => {
  // Animation not ready yet

  const sectionRef = useRef(null);
  const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: sectionRef,
    offset: ["end end", "start start"],
  });

  const position = useTransform(
    scrollYProgress,
    [0, 1],
    ["absolute", "sticky"]
  );

  const height = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [1, 0], ["100vh", "0"]);

  // Animation not ready yet

  return (
    <motion.section
      ref={sectionRef}
      className={`top-0 left-0 flex gap-x-2 w-full h-screen p-4 bg-cc-brown ${className}`}
    >
      <div className="w-[40%] rounded-30px bg-cc-invert flex flex-col justify-between items-center p-30px ">
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-1/2 w-full ">
          <p className="text-cc-brown uppercase font-dmMono text-xs mb-[30px]">
            {activityName}
          </p>
          <h2 className="text-[68px] leading-[51px] w-[520px] text-cc-dark-brown text-center font-youthTrialMedium">
            {title}
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-between h-1/2 w-full">
          <div className="flex flex-col items-center w-full">
            <Separator className="bg-cc-dark-brown opacity-20 mb-12" />
            <p className="text-cc-dark-brown font-youthTrialRegular text-center text-base opacity-80 w-[400px]">
              {text}
            </p>
          </div>
          {linkText !== undefined && linkUrl !== "" && (
            <Link
              href={linkUrl}
              className="p-30px uppercase font-dmMono text-xs bg-cc-light-brown w-full text-center rounded-15px"
            >
              {linkText}
            </Link>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-[60%] min-w-[60%] relative">
        <div className="absolute w-full h-full top-0 left-0 rounded-30px bg-to-top-black-gradient" />
        <Image
          src={imageUrl}
          className={`w-full h-full object-cover rounded-30px`}
          alt={activityName}
          width="2000"
          height="2000"
        />
      </div>
    </motion.section>
  );
};

export default ActivityFieldsSection;


what your gonna need is:useTransform,useScroll hooks, position absolute and sticky and use the dvh for the containers height
(i was gonna make it and post the code but i think its better that you search and try for days )

Hi, thanks for your commet! I got the scrolling feature to work, where it starts from the bottom and sticks to the top. What I am struggling with is creating the revealing effect that starts from the bottom and shows the bottom of the section first. Could you please take a look at it? Here is a screenshot of the code: https://paste.pics/06e6f16adcb20715b088ac037d944075
